# Redshift query runs forever from only 2 mins by just changing a specific number to a variable

Tags: amazon-redshift

My query will automatically update every month in rundeck with updated date by using sysdate.

Here is the first query to generate the time variables for further use.

```
create temp table variables as 
select dateadd('MONTH', 0, sysdate) as endMonth,
       dateadd('MONTH', 1, sysdate) as endMonthPlusOne,
--       dateadd('MONTH', -12, sysdate) as startMonth,
       dateadd('MONTH', -1, sysdate) as startMonth
;
```

Here is my second query:

```
create table ml_data.user_events_filtered distkey(userid) sortkey(eventid) as
select *
  from user_events
 where 1=1
   and eventid=1011 
   and servertime_monthly = date_trunc('month', (select startMonth 
                                                 from variables limit 1))
```

This will run forever until I changed the query to:

```
create table ml_data.user_events_filtered distkey(userid) sortkey(eventid) as
select userid, eventid, clienttime, charparam1, charparam2, charparam3, charparam4
  from user_events
 where 1=1
   and eventid=1011 
   and servertime_monthly = '2015-01-01'
;
```

It takes 2 mins to run. I checked every possible reasons. Does it has something to do with leader node. I don't know if the query planner compile the subquery into a fixed date before running the primary query. I ask this questions since if I only run the subquery, it takes 0.3s. Since my table has huge number of rows, in total it might sum up to a formidable number. The table user_events contains 40 billion rows.

Per Sami's response, I run the EXPLAIN clause for both of the code and here is my result.

```
XN Seq Scan on user_events  (cost=0.01..434963947.53 rows=205328 width=65)
  Filter: ((eventid = 1011) AND ((servertime_monthly)::timestamp without time zone = date_trunc('month'::text, $0)))
  InitPlan
    ->  XN Limit  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=8)
          ->  XN Seq Scan on variables  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=8)



XN Seq Scan on user_events  (cost=0.00..326222960.64 rows=2945182 width=65)
  Filter: ((eventid = 1011) AND (servertime_monthly = '2015-01-01'::date))
```

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to get an idea what the query planner does and post the results for both queries so others can also see what's going on.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I just posted the result of EXPLAIN clause.

Comment: If you provide a constant, the planner can use it at planning-time to do things like pick partial indexes, exclude unwanted partitions, etc. I imagine something like that is going on, but I don't know Redshift well enough to provide detail.

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you want to achieve. Are you really looking for a single event_id, and why do you sort by it.
Why don't you simply use sysdate in your query, and  you create this temp table that is visible only in the current session.

Comment: @Guy Thanks for your replay Guy! Actually sortkey is descended from the original query. I break the original query down to two querys. Regardless, the sortkey has nothing to do with the speed I guess? sysdate will change overtime throughout the entire transaction. I will take your comment for now to see if it improves the performance.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, I guess it might be the reason. I don't know if there is any other ways to fetch data for the most recent month without a subquery or a function in where clause.